# Looking for the Justice League (?) comic book that has the cover page mentioning the Coronavirus (?)

Tags: story-identification, dc, comics, justice-league

In one of the late 2018 episodes of *The Big Bang Theory* (*Season 12, Episode 12*), when Raj gets a call from his dad, there are some comics on his table one of which had the title "**The Coronav___**"; maybe thats why it caught my eye (*images below, click to enlarge*).

[image]

[image]

I was curious and tried to find this comic book online but no luck. Which story-arc/series does this comic come under?

Comment: How did you ever notice such a minute detail?

Comment: @M.A.Golding its the coronavirus! it catches your eye.. kinda weird i know.. but :/

Comment: The real question is if the coronavirus has ever mentioned justice league :P

Answer (score 54, accepted):

This is [Justice League Volume 4 #9](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Justice_League_Vol_4_9) (fandom link)

> IN DEEPEST SPACE LURK...**THE CORONAVORES!**

The cover shows Superman beset by one of the said creatures.

Cover artists are Jim Cheung and Tomeu Morey.

*(There are images at the link but I'm not sure they're copyright-free)*.

Comment: Coronavores. The pandemic has made me crazy I guess. I’m seeing coronavirus everywhere 

Comment: @Shreedhar At this point, I think that would be the first thing anyone would have thought of seeing "CORONAV--"

Comment: They eat... crowns?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite looks like the eat stars, hence the "corona"

Comment: @PaulD.Waite On the link in Spencer's answer, it says that they feed on solar energy, probably taken out of the solar corona. Pretty hot, up there, but not the same as eating whole stars....